# QML FileDialog breaking fonts and text when opening

Tags: qt, qml, qfiledialog

I have a very simple `FileDialog` that, when opened, breaks a bunch of text. My text is being replaced by weird icons and it's reporting an error.

Here's my `FileDialog` qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0
Item{
    property string dialog_title
    property string urls

    signal emitUrl(var urls)

    onUrlsChanged: {
        emitUrl(urls)
    }

    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        title: dialog_title
        folder:shortcuts.home
        onAccepted: {
            urls = fileDialog.fileUrl
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            visible = true
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the error reported:

> load glyph failed err=6 face=0x205e7e0, glyph=85
>  load glyph failed
>   err=6 face=0x205e7e0, glyph=74
>  load glyph failed err=6
>   face=0x205e7e0, glyph=83
>  load glyph failed err=6 face=0x205e7e0,
>   glyph=70
>  load glyph failed err=6 face=0x205e7e0, glyph=72
>  load
>   glyph failed err=6 face=0x205e7e0, glyph=81
>  Warning:
>   distance-field glyph is not available with index 81
>  Warning:
>   distance-field glyph is not available with index 84
>  Warning:
>   distance-field glyph is not available with index 76 ...

And here's how the "Open" and "Cancel" buttons look like in the `FileDialog`:
[image]

I am not sure if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: Not sure whether you've already solve this yet. I'm having difficulties understanding where the trouble is. When I slap the code on top of an `ApplicationWindow` it works just fine. How are you calling your `FileDialog` qml? Please provide a [_mcve_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I did more work on this and then left it for a while. I noticed that I only need to include a FileDialog tag inside my main.qml for it to mess all the TextFields inside my app. I call the `FileDialog` by calling its id `fileDialog.visible = true` when a button is clicked

Comment: MVCE works fine with same conditions. might just close this and start taking elements out one at a time to close in on the issue.

Comment: I switched to `import Qt.labs.platform 1.0` and to `QApplication` instead of `QGuiApplication` and I don't see the problem anymore.